# Trying to render data d3 crossfilter dc.js BarChart. The chart is drawn, but it's empty

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, crossfilter, dc.js

I must be doing something naive, but I can't get my data to render within the chart.

here's my example data:

```
var data = [
    {    
       date: '02-12-2013',
       val: 13,
    }
    {    
       date: '02-13-2013',
       val: 6,
    }
    ...
]
```

here's my code:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var dim = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.val });
var group = dim.group();
var barchart = dc.barChart('#container');

barchart.width(850)
.height(250)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
.dimension(dim)
.group(group)
.gap(1)
.x(d3.time.scale()
          .domain([new Date(data[0].date), 
                  new Date(data[data.length-1].date)]))
.xUnits(d3.time.day)
.centerBar(true)
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.renderVerticalGridLines(true)
.render();
```

What am I missing here? Here's the screenshot of the chart:

[image: Here's the screenshot of the chart]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `date` as your dimension:

```
var dim = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.date });
```

For bar chart your dimension usually is what needs to be matched with your `X` axis scale.